# How can I filter Close Financial Periods records by a user field's value?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a customization that worked in an older version of Acumatica, but has stopped working when upgraded.

I've customized the AP screens to add a user field to APRegister so that the BQL query that gathers records for the 'Close Financial Periods' process can filter out records with a specific user field's value (in this case, "N/A").   Here's a screenshot of the BQL query (Assuming this is still the query that gathers records for the 'Close Financial Periods' process) that we've altered in previous versions of Acumatica in order to filter out these records - the user field is added to the where clause:

[image]

As I said, this worked in previous versions of Acumatica but does not work now.   I've tried to add several variations of this user field in different areas of this BQL query, and even added a WhereAnd<> clause at the end of the GetCommand() action.  None of them work.

Bottom line:  What can I use NOW to filter out records from the 'Close Financial Periods' process?

Thanks much...